# Javascript Assignment Operators with transform

Tags: javascript, styles, operators

if I have element,and I want to translate it for 50px more than the current value.Why I can't do something like this?

```
element.style.transform="translateX(+=50px)"
```

Is there a way to do something like that?

Answer (score 2):

If your transform is set in a stylesheet, `element.style.transform` will return an empty string. You must use [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle).

To get the x translation as an integer use:

```
var transform = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(element, null).transform.split(',')[4]);
```

Then use this to increment by 50 pixels:

```
element.style.transform = "translateX(" + (transform + 50) + "px)"
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uhuh9r64/

Answer (score -1):

JS does not understand CSS and vice versa, but CSS can solve this on its own.

Unknown to most people, the ECMAScript (proper name for JS) specification and the CSS and DOM standards are maintained by different groups and have little ability for interoperation. Most interfacing between them happens with JS invoking the APIs, but JS does not typically consider or care what API it invokes.

That is, JS has no explicit support for CSS and sees this as a string.

That doesn't matter when you can [transform elements using pure CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transforms/Using_CSS_transforms), without JS needing to be involved (although you can apply transforms from JS). A simple position transform, even in 2D, can easily move an element down by 50px.

Comment: But you can parse that string.

Comment: @Feathercrown which is a rather poor choice, since other options exist.

Comment: I was using TweenMax and simply did x="+=100px",do you maybe know how they did that?

Comment: @ssube But what if in this case this is the only option he has? It's likely that it isn't, but it could be

Comment: @Matija you should check their source. It's likely that they are managing all of the properties in their own code, which is possible, but expensive and error-prone.

Answer (score -2):

The translateX() is a css function used to move the element horizontally on the plane. This transformation is define by a `length` that define how much it moves in horizontally. The sample code example is for you in the bellow.....

exm.html

```
<div>
  <p>welcome</p>
  <p class="transformed">bar</p>
  <p>thanks</p>
</div>
```

exm.css

```
p { 
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: teal;
}

.transformed {
  transform: translateX(10px);
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: This does not modify the existing transform, which the OP explicitly asks for: "I want to translate it for 50px more than the current value"